# Memory leak in C++ function using std::swap

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I'm using qt creator and I'm having trouble with a memory leak. I've read some posts about dynamic memory allocation but from what I've seen, I can't understand why my function is accumulating something in memory.

I'm completely sure I've pinpointed the function that causes the problem:

```
void CSimWindow::cloneNet(int origin, int destination)

    int newNumSensors = netVector[origin].getNumSensors();
    int newNumActuators = netVector[origin].getNumActuators();
    int newNumNeurons = netVector[origin].getNumNeurons();

    CNet newNet(newNumNeurons, 0);
    newNet.setNumSensors(newNumSensors);
    newNet.setNumActuators(newNumActuators);

    for (int i = 0; i < netVector[origin].getNumNeurons(); i++)
    {
        ...
    }
    std::swap(newNet, netVector[destination]);

}
```

I'm quite a newbie, but as I understand it, the objects created inside the function should be destroyed when it's finished. If anyone can tell me why this function causes the memory leak, I thank you in advance.

Comment: **a.** how is CNet defined? **b.** how do you _detect_ the memory leak **c.** what's the use of cloning the net if you're going to drop the original immediately (is there any state you are explicitely not copying?)

Comment: You can't leak if you never allocate memory: the leak is in code you haven't shown us. As sehe says, CNet is suspicious, but mostly because it's right in our face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it there are three possibilities:

1: (the most likely) the CNet destructor does not properly de-allocate memory that is reserved by its constructor.

To check that, use a global `CNet newNet` variable, and do not re-create temporary variables every time you go into this routine (rather just set the values of the global `newNet` variable), so you do not keep calling the constructor/destructor.

2: The `std::swap(newNet, netVector[destination]);` call, which I think creates a temporary variable as explained here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

Try to comment the `std::swap` call and see what happens.

3: Something inside the for loop is fishy, but you do not provide details there.

Good luck.